# On LyX 2.3.7 for macOS, full screen option have no effect

Tags: lyx, macos

Changing fullscreen options (Preferences > Editing > Control) has no effect. Text width remains unchanged, toolbars don't disappear, but the menu bar *is* hidden. I find no reports on this elsewhere, but maybe someone has a clue?

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure, after you change the preferences, you've tried activating "full screen mode" by going to View > Full Screen, right?

Comment: Yes. And relaunched LyX, and tried again... It happens on both my iMac (M1) and my MacBook (Intel).

Comment: I have no idea. My only shot-in-the-dark guess is that it is yet another issue related to updating to Ventura. We've seen weird things due to that. I believe LyX 2.4.0 should help in that regard, but it's not going to be released for a few months.